# Java Null Pointer Exception when inserting into a local database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add a username into a .accdb local database. My code is as followed:

```
try
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES('?');";
        System.out.println("SQL : " + sql);

        System.out.println("USER : " + user);

        PreparedStatement stmt = database.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.println("Statement : " + stmt);
        stmt.setString(1, user); 
        System.out.println("Statement : " + stmt);

        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(); 
        System.out.println("Results : " + results);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlEx)
    {
        System.out.println("* Cannot execute insertion! *");
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

The console output is :

```
SQL : INSERT INTO Users VALUES('?');
USER : TEST
Statement : sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement@1bf73fa
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.clearParameter    (JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1023)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setChar    (JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:3057)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setString    (JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:766)
at MultiEchoServer.addRegisteredUser(MultiEchoServer.java:100)
at ClientHandler.run(MultiEchoServer.java:339)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look at the stack trace and figure out why the reference on line 339 is NULL.  Also, it's 'Java' not 'JAVA'.

Comment: @Corbin:) You have edit privileges, you know.

Comment: @Lion Yes, I've already edited it.  I just wanted to explicitly point it out so the question asker is more likely to notice.  I don't know why, but I've noticed lately that about 40% of Java questions have Java stylized as 'JAVA' (and for some reason it bugs the hell out of me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the problem, I suspect:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES('?');";
```

That statement doesn't *have* any parameters - it will always insert a question mark, because you've got it in quotes so it's a *value* rather than a parameter. I think you want:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?)";
```

(Note that I've removed the extra semi-colon at the end of the SQL statement too - I don't believe you really want that.)

It's unfortunate that the exception isn't more helpful, admittedly... I'd expect something to indicate that index 1 was out of range.

Comment: I was going to say that the semi-colon at the end of the SQL shouldn't matter, but I'd also expect the PreparedStatement class being used to handle an invalid parameter binding a bit more gracefully and throw a useful exception, so I really can't be sure about that.

Comment: You're dependent on JDBC driver make/version as to the properness of validating and exception handling. The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver indeed belongs to the worst ones. Not only in the area of exception handling...

Answer (score 6):

Remove the quotes and the semicolon:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?)";
```